# Smelling the Haddas when the first day is Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, smell

According to the Ta”z (OC 665), who holds that it is forbidden to smell the Haddas once it was bundled - even before it was used for the Mitzvah - is one permitted to smell it on the first day of Sukkos when it fell out on Shabbos, being that the Mitzvah has not yet arrived?

Comment: Why would it be assur, as you said there is no mitzvah yet

Comment: @wfb I’m just wondering why no one says so, the way it is brought down with regards to Shofar, when Rosh Hashanah is on Shabbos

Comment: A shofar is muktzeh, so is a hadas but if you don't move it presumably you can smell it

Comment: @wfb, but you may not derive any benefit from it on Rosh Hashanah when it falls out on a weekday

Comment: See here - http://rabbikaganoff.com/may-i-smell-my-esrog-and-hadasim-on-sukkos-2/

Comment: No according to this but no source - https://outorah.org/p/18847/